# I'm having issues with a segmentation fault C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to open a file and see how many lines, words, character, and sentences are in the file. Everything compiles fine, but when the program runs, it prints the instructions then there is a "segmentation fault(core dumped)" error. I know the file opens fine, so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong in processFile. Help would be great!

P.S. the #include "lib09.h" are the three functions after main()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lib09.h"

int main(void)
{
   FILE *fileIn;
   int *lines = 0,
        *words = 0,
        *sentences = 0,
        *characters = 0;


   printInstructions();

   fileIn = fopen("input09.txt", "r");

   if (fileIn == NULL)
        {
        printf("\n\nERROR\n");
        printf("FILE DOES NOT EXIST.\n");
        printf("TRY AGAIN\n\n");
        }

   else
        {
        processFile(fileIn);
        printReport(lines, words, characters, sentences);
        }

   return 0;
}

//
//Prints Instructions
//
void printInstructions()
{
   printf("\n====================================================\n");
   printf("  Program reads a file and returns the number of  \n");
   printf("lines, words, characters, and sentences in the file.\n");
   printf("====================================================\n\n");

   return;
}

//
//Processes File
//
int processFile(FILE *fileIn)
{
        int ch,
        *lines = 0,
        *sentences = 0,
        *characters = 0,
        *words = 0;

   while(fscanf(fileIn, "%d", &ch) != EOF)
   {
      ch = fgetc(fileIn);

                if(ch == '\n' || ch == 60)
                        return *lines++;

                if(ch == '.')
                        return *sentences++;

                if(ch != ' ' || ch != '.' || ch != '\n')
                        return *characters++;

                if(ch == ' ')
                        return *words++;
   }

   fclose(fileIn);

   return 0;
}

//
//Prints Values from File
//
void printReport(int *words, int  *lines, int *characters, int *sentences)
{
   printf("This file contains %d lines.\n", *lines);
   printf("This file contains %d words.\n", *words);
   printf("This file contains %d characters.\n", *characters);
   printf("This file contains %d sentences.\n\n", *sentences);

   return;
}
```

Comment: You're writing to four different null pointers in your `processFile()` function. Pretty sure you meant to pass those as by-address input parameters to the function, and pass `&var` parameters back in the caller-side. Of course, the function itself is wrong anyway, since it will incorrectly return the moment any char is processed anyway. I don't think, given the name of the function *any* of those `return` statements should be there.

Comment: Ah yes, the daily "I write to memory cells where nothing exists why do I get segfault" question. Vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at main:

```
int lines = 0,
    words = 0,
    sentences = 0,
    characters = 0;
...
processFile(fileIn, &lines, &word,&sentences, &characters);
```

at processFile

```
processFile(FILE* fileIn, int* lines, int* word, int* sentences, int* characters){
...
}
```

note:

`fscanf(fileIn, "%d", &ch)` <- wrong

`return *lines++;` <- do not return

Answer (score 0):

The *lines, *words etc are all pointers which are never initialized to proper memory addresses.

If you create them outside main as ints and remove all *prefixes it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make these ints not pointers to int

```
 *lines = 0,
 *sentences = 0,
 *characters = 0,
 *words = 0;
```

by removing the * in each one and also when you increment them